# std::unordered_map::begin(int n) behavior

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, unordered-map

Here's the code I'm running, with g++ 4.6 and `-std=c++0x`

```
std::unordered_map<int, int> um;

um.insert(std::make_pair(42, 43));
um.insert(std::make_pair(342, 343));
um.insert(std::make_pair(142, 143));
um.insert(std::make_pair(242, 243));

for(auto e : um)
std::cout << e.first << std::endl;
```

This prints:

```
242
342
42
142
```

Now I can access 242 with `um.begin()->first` or `um.begin(0)->first`. 342 can be accessed using `um.begin(1)->first`. But `um.begin(2)->first` or `um.begin(3)->first` make the program crash. With different numbers I was able to access `um.begin(2)->first`.
I cannot explain that behavior to myself. Do I use `um.begin(int)` wrong?

Comment: I quite doubt about `int` being used. It is more probably a `size_type` inner typedef referring to `std::size_t`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. you're right. but it doesn't change much

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You got this very confused. `begin(1)` is a very special construction only for the unordered containers that accesses a specific *bucket* in the underlying hash table structure and returns a *local iterator*. That has nothing to do with accessing any specific element in a sort of "random access" way, which you simply cannot do.

All you can do with an unordered container is iterate over the entire collection or `find` a specific element by key. The elements are not accessible in any particular order, whence the name "unordered".

You *can* use the local iterators to iterate over each bucket `[begin(n), end(n))`, but of course you have to use the same idioms that you use for any range to deal with empty containers. The total number of buckets available can be discovered with the `bucket_count` member function.

Note that in most situations you should expect a bucket to contain either zero or one elements. The average number of elements per bucket is available (and configurable) via the `load_factor` member function.